# Resolving system with Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, chinese-remainder-theorem

Consider following system : \begin{cases} x  \equiv 2 \, \text{mod} \,  9   \\ x \equiv 3 \, \text{mod} \, 5 \\ x \equiv 8 \ \text{mod} \, 21 \end{cases}
I can't apply the Chinese remainder theorem because the $\text{gcd}(21,9) \neq 1.$ So I want to factorize $21$ and $9$ in prime factors and make new equations. A theorem in my books says if the $\text{gcd}(n,m) = 1$ then $ x \equiv x' \, \text{mod}\ nm  \iff \begin{cases} x  \equiv x' \, \text{mod} \,  n   \\ x \equiv x' \, \text{mod} \, m \\ \end{cases} $. But how do I apply this with the first equation. Because $9=3*3$ and the $\text{gcd}(3,3) \neq 1$. I heard some solution who said that $x \equiv 2\,\text{mod}\, 9$ is the same as  $x \equiv 2\,\text{mod}\, 3$ but I don't understand why they are the same. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: $5\equiv2\pmod3$ but $5\not\equiv2\pmod9$

Comment: Please see the linked dupes for the basic ideas (explained in general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Since $21=3\cdot 7$, by CRT, the system is equivalent to
$$\begin{cases} x  \equiv 2 \, \text{mod} \,  9   \\ x \equiv 3 \, \text{mod} \, 5 \\ x \equiv 8 \ \text{mod} \, 3\\ x \equiv 8 \ \text{mod} \, 7 \end{cases}$$
That is
$$\begin{cases} x  \equiv 2 \, \text{mod} \,  9   \\ x \equiv 3 \, \text{mod} \, 5 \\ x \equiv 2 \ \text{mod} \, 3\\ x \equiv 1 \ \text{mod} \, 7 \end{cases}$$
Since $x \equiv 2\ \text{mod} \, 9$ implies  $x \equiv 2\ \text{mod} \, 3$,it remains to solve
$$\begin{cases} x  \equiv 2 \, \text{mod} \,  9   \\ x \equiv 3 \, \text{mod} \, 5 \\ x \equiv 1 \ \text{mod} \, 7 \end{cases}$$
Now apply CRT.

Comment: It is just the hint that I don't understand... Why you can replace it...

Comment: By CRT, $x \equiv 8 \ \text{mod} \, (3\cdot 7)$ is equivalent to $x \equiv 8 \ \text{mod} \, 3$ AND $x \equiv 8 \ \text{mod} \, 7$.

Comment: And why is x≡2 mod9 then x≡2 mod3?

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this. It is a correct answer. It addresses both of the non-prime moduli by showing the system is consistent. Example of a non-consistent system: $$\begin{cases}x \equiv 2 \pmod{9} \\ x \equiv 3\pmod{5} \\ x\equiv 10\pmod{21}\end{cases}$$ Which is easily shown to be inconsistent since $x\equiv 2\pmod{9} \Longrightarrow x\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, but $x\equiv 10\pmod{21} \Longrightarrow x\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Kabouter9 I edited my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: I'm still struggling with $x \equiv 2 \, mod \,9$ implies $x \equiv 2 \, mod \, 3$. Intuitive it is clear, but I don't have a mathematical explanation for it.

Comment: $x \equiv 2 \, mod \,9$ means that $x=9q+2=3(3q)+2$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks you all!